# ¿Como Convertir un archivo file a String base 64 con javascript en jsp?

Tags: javascript, file, struts, base64, blob

Una ayuda , necesito convertir el archivo file (foto jpg) a String base64 y asi  enviarlo como  un String a travez del json o mi action reserva.

> La vista jsp donde declaro el File

[image: imagen1]

> Json donde envio los valores ingresados a el action reserva

[image: imagen2]

> Action reserva quienrecibe las variables tipo String. 
>   Ademas como convetiria el String base 64 que reciba en el action para guardarlo en mi bd  como blob

[image: imagen3]

> Error consola:
>   Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
>   Unexpected Exception caught setting 'fotosBytes' on 'class com.redsocial.action.ProgramacionAction: Error setting expression 'fotosBytes' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@3067000'
>   ERROR [http-nio-8081-exec-2] - Could not find action or result
>   /DAWI_Sistema_Canchitav_vEdu_v6/reservar?textoReserva=zzzz&fechaInicio=2017-11-13+15%3A30%3A00&fechaFin=2017-11-13+16%3A00%3A00&dniCliente=123&fotosBytes=C%3A%5Cfakepath%5C0.jpg&promocion=Cuadro&idCancha=1
>   No result defined for action com.redsocial.action.ProgramacionAction and result input

Comment: puedes agregar tu codigo en vez de imagenes

Comment: Las imágenes no se pueden compilar, pon el código de verdad.

Comment: Bueno lo editaria mas tarde solo que e codigo no lo tengo a la mano , ¿Pero fue clara mi pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo utilice la siguiente función para convertir los archivos o imágenes a base 64

```
function SelectedFile() {
        //Toma el archivo elegido por el input 
        var value = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

        //Este objeto FileReader te permite leer archivos
        var reader = new FileReader();

        //Esta función se ejecuta cuando el reader.readAsDataURL termina 
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            NombreDeTuVariableAEnviar = e.target.result.split("base64,")[1];
        }

        //Aqui comienza a leer el archivo para posteriormente ejecutar la función onloadend
        reader.readAsDataURL(value);

}
```

[Aquí puedes consultar la documentación sobre como utilizar FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
,el guardado en base de datos te lo debo, espero te sea de ayuda, Saludos.