# ¿Como pasar una imagen a BASE64?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo un archivo del tipo FILE en JavaScript, quisiera saber como podria hacer para pasarlo a Base64?

Comment: Podrías utilizar http://jpillora.com Crea data:URI por transferencia de archivos con "arrastrar y soltar". También podrías hacerlo pintando la imagen en un elemento canvas y utilizar el canvas para conseguir el data:URI [Crear data:uri desde canvas](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/canvas/toDataURL.php). Por favor lea esto acerca de como hacerlo utilizando [el evento drag](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/lab/drag-event.php)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como Convertir un archivo file a String base 64 con javascript en jsp?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118759/como-convertir-un-archivo-file-a-string-base-64-con-javascript-en-jsp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prodias apoyarte con el FileReader

```
    let reader= new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
    reader.onload=()=>{
        //aqui ya esta en base64
        let x=reader.result;
   }
```

Comment: Es mejor usar esta opcion, pero no es recomendable en dispositivos moviles, en mi caso `FileReader` falla siempre para archivos mas pesados que 150mb.